# Checking two lists for Modifications

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ienumerable

I have got two lists of **two different type** which has the following common properties.

`Id` -->used to identify corresponding objects

`Bunch of other Properties`

`ModificationDate`

Need to compare these two lists based on Modification date.If the modified date is different (first list `ModificationDate` greater than second list's `ModificationDate` then, copy all the properties if that item from first list to second.

Please let me know the best way to do this.

EDITED:Second list may or maynot contain all elements of the first and vice versa.My first list is always the source list. so if an item is present in list 1 and not present in list 2 we need to add it in list 2. also if an item  present in list 2 but in not in list 1 then remove it from list2.

Comment: Based on your edit, it sounds like List2 just needs to look like List1? Why not delete List2, and make another copy of List1 to replace it?

Comment: i'm doing it via a Nhibernate.so deleting everything is not a solution as we have a cascade delete with some other tables as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided link was helpful in comparing two lists of different types

[Comparing Collections in .Net](http://robertbouillon.wordpress.com/2010/04/29/comparing-collections-in-net/)

Answer (score 5):

### Finding added/deleted items

```
var list1 = new List<MyType>();
var list2 = new List<MyType>();

// These two assume MyType : IEquatable<MyType>
var added = list1.Except(list2);
var deleted = list2.Except(list1);

// Now add "added" to list2, remove "deleted" from list2
```

If `MyType` does not implement `IEquatable<MyType>`, or the implementation is not based solely on comparing ids, you will need to create an `IEqualityComparer<MyType>`:

```
class MyTypeIdComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyType>
{
    public bool Equals(MyType x, MyType y)
    {
        return x.Id.CompareTo(y.Id);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyType obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Which will allow you to do:

```
// This does not assume so much for MyType
var comparer = new MyTypeIdComparer();
var added = list1.Except(list2, comparer);
var deleted = list2.Except(list1, comparer);
```

### Finding modified items

```
var modified = list1.Concat(list2)
                    .GroupBy(item => item.Id)
                    .Where(g => g.Select(item => item.ModificationDate)
                                 .Distinct().Count() != 1);

// To propagate the modifications:
foreach(var grp in modified) {
    var items = grp.OrderBy(item => item.ModificationDate);
    var target = items.First(); // earliest modification date = old
    var source = grp.Last();    // latest modification date = new

    // And now copy properties from source to target
}
```

Comment: In the first example am I silly to think that you will always end up with an exact duplicate of list1? +1 for your modified version.

Comment: @Jon. the two list are not going to be the same type.i have modified the question.so does this work `list1.Concat(list2) `

Comment: @AshleyJohn: In that case you have to make them implement the same interface and use that interface as the "same" type. Otherwise it's going to be **very** painful.

Answer (score 1):

This might be able to help. The Linq library has lots of decent functions, such as Except, Intersection.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397894.aspx